# How to filter a big JSON with a small JSON using jq?

Tags: json, bash, select, jq

I hava a big JSON and I want to filter the content whith multiple conditions, in other words, fetch the specific items which specific values.

This process is based on `jq(v1.5)` and `bash`.

json-a (just a example):

```
[
   {
    "city": "abc"
   },
   {
    "city": "def"
   },
   {
    "city": "ghi"
   },
  {
    "city": "jkl"
   }
]
```

Now, I want to get {"city": "abc"} and {"city": "ghi"} but don't want to pass for-loop with bash (i think `jq` is a great tool with its own loop function).

So I built a small json contains specific values.

json-b(just a example):

```
["abc","ghi"]
```

and execute jq command:

```
$ json-b='["abc","ghi"]'
$ cat json-a | jq --argjson arg ${json-b} '.[] | select( ($arg|index(.city)) )' # return error
error: Cannot index array with string "city"

$ cat json-a | jq --argjson arg ${json-b} '.[] | select( ($arg|index( \(.city) )) )' # return error
error: compile error

# BUT
$ cat json-a | jq --argjson arg ${json} '.[] | .city as $c | select( ($arg|index($c)) )' # It's work
```

> So, the output Object cannot be called by builtin funciton? I tried `in`,`contains` does not work too.
>   Did I do something wrong there? Or is there better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `.` inside the `select` does not reference a row from you input array  , but `$arg` because of the inside `|`

This is your working example

```
$ echo  '[{"c":"a"},{"c":"d"},{"c":"g"},{"c":"j"}]' | \
        jq '.[] | .c as $c | select( ["a","g"] | index($c) ) '
{
  "c": "a"
}
{
  "c": "g"
}
```

Now we `replace` select by `map`

```
$ echo  '[{"c":"a"},{"c":"d"},{"c":"g"},{"c":"j"}]' | \
             jq '.[] | .c as $c | map( ["a","g"] | index($c) ) '
[
  0
]
[
  null
]
[
  1
]
[
  null
]
```

Now instead of `index($c)` we replace by `.`

```
$ echo  '[{"c":"a"},{"c":"d"},{"c":"g"},{"c":"j"}]' | \
             jq '.[] | .c as $c | map( ["a","g"] | . ) '
[
  [
    "abc",
    "ghi"
  ]
]
[
  [
    "abc",
    "ghi"
  ]
]
[
  [
    "abc",
    "ghi"
  ]
]
[
  [
    "abc",
    "ghi"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Finally figured out why `.city` cannot be placed in `index( )` .

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a working solution, let me first mention that if you want the results as an array, you could write:

```
jq --argfile array json-b.json '
  map(select( .city as $city | $array | index($city)))
' json-a.json
```

However, it would probably be better to put the jq program into a file and invoke jq with the -f option:

```
jq -f program.jq --argfile array json-b.json json-a.json
```

### Explanations for the unsuccessful attempts

#### `$arg|index(.city)`

The reason why your first attempt cannot work in the way intended is that
`$arg|index(.city)` is exactly equivalent to `$arg|index($arg.city)`, which is obviously not what's needed.

#### `index( \(.city) )`

This expression is just syntactically invalid.  Perhaps you had string interpolation in mind; if so, the expression would be `index("\(.city)")`, but that has the same problem as noted in the previous section.

Comment: Finally figured out why `.city` cannot be placed in `index( )` , `|` is very powerful.

Comment: BTW, using the option `-f` is a good suggestion. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

> is there better way?

Here's a solution that has a number of potential advantages as outlined below:

```
< json-a.json jq --argfile array json-b.json '
  INDEX(.city)[$array[]]'
```

Notice that the time-complexity of this algorithm is approximately O(n) + O(m) where n and m are the lengths of the two arrays.  By contrast, naively iterating through the array of objects and checking against the array of relevant cities has time-complexity O(n)*O(m).

Another advantage is that this solution does not use `index/1`, the implementation of which is currently suboptimal.

### Caveat

If there is more than one object in the main array with the same value of .city, then the results may or may not be as wanted.

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Actually, the value of `json-b` is not exactly the same as the value of `json-b`, similar to fuzzy query. Maybe I can try `contains()` . Thank you, this is a clever statement.